# Как получить название валюты на основании локали браузера?

Tags: javascript

Как получить название валюты на основании локали браузера?

Например:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || 'en'; // ru
    
// На основании ru нужно получить RUB и т.д. (us ---> USD)
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let map = {ru: 'RUB', en: 'USD'};
let lang = 'ru';
console.log(map[lang]);
lang = 'en';
console.log(map[lang]);
```

Comment: это понятно, а если валют будет больше 170?

Comment: Ну перечисли все необходимые.  Если ты хочешь, чтобы тебе посоветовали использовать какое-то api, то ты, получается, и так об этом знаешь ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: всё таки правильнее определять валюту не на основе языка, а в зависимости от страны

Comment: @mymedia это уж как ТС решит, что ему надо